# find all UIView on given point in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

Is there a way to find all UIView items positioned over a given point? I have a Swift project with a custom keyboard. The footer has four buttons and the taps are not working. I think perhaps there's an overlapping view which is higher in the Z-order so it blocks the taps, but transparent so I can't see it.
I didn't write it so I'm not sure about what view might be doing this. If I can pick a point and find all views that cover that point then I could use reflection to find out which of our extensions of UIView it might be.

Thanks
Mike

Comment: Use the "Debug View Hierarchy" feature of Xcode.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy. Unfortunately I see "Unable to capture view hierarchy. Check the console log for additional information." I don't see anything in the console log. Perhaps it fails because this is a keyboard extension and not the main app?

Comment: Are these buttons on top of an image. Is user interaction disabled on the image view ?  Hide the views one by one and check.

Comment: The buttons are UIView with UITapGestureRecognizer. The buttons work when we first start it up in portrait mode. They work when we switch to landscape. After that they don't work in portrait any more, only in landscape. This only happens on iPad in portrait mode. I moved them up 80 px and they work so it appears there's something wrong with the bottom 80px but I can't figure out what.

Comment: OK got it figured out. Had nothing to do with view overlap, it was actually being truncated. `clipsToBounds` was false so I couldn't see that it was being clipped. But we override `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and there I could see that the size that we set to 264 in height was being cut off to 176. I have no idea why but I can take care of it there.